# Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitor with small dent still usable?

Tags: safety, electrolytic-capacitor

I have three 10000µF 75V Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors. The aluminum can has a very shallow dent. Would you think this is still safe to use them? I have three of them, and they are expensive

Comment: This probably depends on how they got dented. Was it due to purely mechanical means or did it occur while they were being used in a circuit?

Comment: Any chance to see a picture?

Comment: we need to see a picture at least. ... there is no telling what you mean by shallow dent ..... there was a post once where the OP said that he `may have scratched his cell phone battery slightly` he posted a picture and it looked like a cat shredded it ... lol

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you could test them with an LCR meter, but a shallow dent is probably not a problem.  A bulge would be a whole diffent matter.

Comment: A dent could be a big problem if the capacitor plate roll inside got compressed in a tight spot due to the dent location.

Answer (score 0):

The best test is measure leakage current at rated V using a large R to slowly charge it up or a low power  <<8W light bulb rated for 120 V then compare with datasheet